# How does a demigod city enjoy freedom while also pretending it is not?

Tags: magic, society, politics, gods

Spill over is never a good thing in nature, from the tragedy befalling Hercules in mythology to the current pandemic are some of the side effects reminding us never to underestimate the power of nature. Then again if anything we learnt from history is that it repeats so there you go a demigod city right here on Earth in the present day, the demigods are descendants of an exiled titan who bullied the town's people hundreds of years ago.

Ruler of Olympus feared the retaliation of titan and so banished the demigods to the mortal plane and give rise to the demigod city, to this day the Olympians still feel disgusted by the existence of demigod but had long forgiven humanity and in fact they love human more than other god.

My question is despite these demigods sticking out like a sore thumb in the eye of the Olympians, how do the rebellious demigods be able maintain their status quo for so long?

Sure there are some major incidents such as the murder of guard dog of hell, massacre of entire Amazoness as well as extinction of centaurs pretty atrocious and clearly an act of defiance against the god, but apparently the demigod city still flourish to this day. Something is amiss so can anyone please enlighten me thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping the demigod city in place is the lesser evil, or better a necessary evil, because its presence, and the presence of the demigods in it, keeps the humans better under control, which the gods know is a cumbersome task.

To put it differently, it's plain old realpolitik: suffering a sore thumb that keeps the human under control is much better than having to deal with policing the humans directly.

Answer (score 2):

**The people there now are the descendants of demigods.**

Just like the Japanese emperor is descended from a sun goddess!

https://www.cnn.com/2019/11/14/asia/japan-emperor-ritual-intl-hnk/index.html

> Since he formally ascended to the Chrysanthemum Throne at the start of
> May, Naruhito has been undertaking a series of ceremonies and rites.
> On Thursday night, he will take part in a mystical, 2.7 billion-yen
> ($24.8 million) ritual known as “Daijosai” – or “rite of great
> feasting” – which will see him sharing a banquet with the Shinto deity
> Amaterasu, the sun goddess traditionally claimed by the Japanese
> Imperial family as one of its divine ancestors.

The demigods got seriously busy in their time.  They left lots of semidemigod progeny.  Dilution is the solution to pollution in the Olympian view and many generations have passed.  The people now residing in the city take great pride in their demigodly heritage.  But they still need to work for a living and any powers an individual might have fall within the realm of human variation.  The godliness has been diluted out.

Except for the one dude who can spit sparks but the Olympians are ok with him.

Answer (score 1):

## They offer fealty to Hera and Demeter and Persephone.

While the gods at large have a strong disagreement with the demigod city, three goddesses, Hera the grandmother, Demeter the child and Perspephone the granddaughter have become close allies with the children of the fallen titan, and shield them from a greater wrath.

The demigods were smarter than their progenitor, and didn't seek to rebel against every god. They offered fealty to Hera and Demeter and Persephone, who blessed them with stable relationships, children, fertile crops, and good plant growth.

## Their incidents were acts of loyalty to their patrons.

The guard dog was murdered because Persephone wanted to go party with her mother away from Hades during winter and they agreed to free her. The Amazons's lesbianism and lack of stable marital relationships was an affront to the law of Hera so they had to go. The centaurs were rapists who broke stable and good relationships, and so they had to go as well.

Any rival god who wants to attack them directly needs to go through the three goddesses, and that's gone badly for them when their cities and cults fade into winter and death, and their people become infertile. Attacking them directly with mortal weapons worked out badly for the amazons and the centaurs.